# Running tomcat 9 embedded on maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

i'm trying to run tomcat 9 embedded through maven.

I saw that there is no 'tomcat9-maven-plugin' yet and that i can run tomcat 9 using tomcat7-plugin but i don't seem to be able to do so.

Things I've tried:

- I've tried to set CATALINA_HOME to the new version path
- Setting version in the plugin's configurations
- Change the version using the the dependencies:

  ```
      <properties>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.0.M1</tomcat.version>
      </properties>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>

                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
                      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
                  </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
           </plugins>
  ```

I don't know what else to try, no matter what i do it always run on version 7.0.47:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Tomcat Maven plugin seems discontinued, but you can use Cargo plugin instead to run embedded Tomcat 9.

Add plugin configuration in pom:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <container>
      <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
      <type>embedded</type>
    </container>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Start it with:

```
mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
```